# cant acces class file because of classpath

Tags: java, reflection, classpath

I'm trying to run a program that uses the classpath to access classes in another directory.

Currently, when I run the project, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cat
```

This is occurring when I try to load the class:

```
Class c = Class.forName(classList.get(i-1));  //Class c = Class.forName("Cat"));
Method[] methods = c.getMethods();
```

Below are the two approaches I'm using for setting the classpath but both approaches result in the same error:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/Users/john/Desktop/TestClass/
java -jar PackageExplorer.jar /Users/john/Desktop/TestClass

java -classpath .:/Users/john/Desktop/TestClass -jar PackageExplorer.jar /Users/john/Desktop/TestClass
```

Update: I moved my code to a plain java file and attempted the same thing and it worked fine. So there is something about doing this with the jar file thats not working. My assumption is that the program can't see the directory for whatever reason. The class file exists and is definitely in that directory.

Comment: Maybe you have a classpath broken. Try this: 
`java -classpath .;yourjar.jar YourMainClass`

Comment: @Gatusko I'm able to run and access the jar and main class fine. I need to set a classpath that tells what directory to search for when this line is executed `Class c = Class.forName(classList.get(i-1));` which is this directory /Users/john/Desktop/TestClass

Comment: Which `jar` are you talking about? There is no `jar` in your class path.

Comment: @Holger Whoops you're right. I updated the post.

Comment: And now, we’ve solved the issue. As [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI): “*When you use the `-jar` option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.*” That’s why it is so important to precisely include all information.

Comment: @Holger wow. That answers the question alright. But how can I go about testing the jar file if the classpath is ignored?

Comment: You can remove the `-jar` option, then manually add the jar file (and all dependencies) to the `-classpath` and specify the jar’s main class. `java -classpath .:/Users/john/Desktop/TestClass:PackageExplorer.jar your.main.Class /Users/john/Desktop/TestClass`